# Create archives by author role

Tags: archives, author-template

I have a site that will have some custom roles (capabilities), and I would like to have archives that list authors based on their role.

authors.php list the profile of one author, but there is no template for listing authors, right?

Is a custom template the only way to do this? I would rather not have empty pages that just serve as holders for my archives.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to abuse [`add_rewrite_endpoint`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint) for this purpose, depending on exactly what you want to do.

Some examples:

```
// add an endpoint
// http:domain.com/role/
// http:domain.com/role/foo/ 
function wpa_add_role_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'role', EP_ALL );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpa_add_role_endpoint' );


// check if a role parameter exists, like:
// http:domain.com/role/foo/
function wpa_role_query( $query ){
    if( $query->get('role') ){
        echo $query->get('role'); // echoes 'foo'
        // modify the query $query->set( 'somevar', 'someval' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa_role_query' );


// check if role is in query vars array, like:
// http:domain.com/role/
function wpa_role_parse( $query ){
    if( array_key_exists( 'role', $query->query_vars ) )
        die('role query');
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpa_role_parse' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Today, wptuts posted an article about exactly this:

http://wp.tutsplus.com/?p=30564